# Extracting value from select element in HTML using XPath Query in JMeter

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, jmeter, load-testing

I want to extract the first value which has the property `selected = "selected"` using XPath extractor. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

The html which i'm extracting the value from is:

```
< select id="ddLocation" name="ddLocation" class="DDlocation" size="1"      onchange="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'onLocationChange();,'mojarra.ab(this,event,\'valueChange\',\'@this\',0)')"> <br>
    < option value="43" selected="selected">Pune</option> <br>
    < option value="44">Agra< /option> <br>
    < option value="45">Guntur< /option> <br>
    < option value="46">Kochi< /option> <br>
    < option value="73">Kothrud< /option> <br>
    < option value="153">Ratnagiri< /option> <br>
    < option value="156">Baner< /option>
```

My XPath query is:

```
//select[@id="ddLocation"]/option[1]/@value
```

Is it wrong?
Can anyone suggest me any better / right approach please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your xml is not in proper format

It has lot of spaces in-front of option and select is not closed at end.

```
<select id="ddLocation" name="ddLocation" class="DDlocation" size="1" onchange="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'onLocationChange();,'mojarra.ab(this,event,\'valueChange\',\'@this\',0)')">
    <option value="43" selected="selected">Pune </option>
    <option value="44">Agra</option>
    <option value="45">Guntur</option>
    <option value="46">Kochi</option>
    <option value="73">Kothrud</option>
    <option value="153">Ratnagiri</option>
    <option value="156">Baner</option>
</select>
```

Finally, your XPATH works as expected.

```
//select[@id="ddLocation"]/option[1]/@value
```

It gives output as **43**

### EDIT:

If you use below XPATH, it gives result according to where attribute is `selected=selected`

```
//select[@id='ddLocation']/option[@selected='selected']/@value
```

I have not tested using JMeter but am checking XPATH on XMLSPY.

Comment: Sorry, I purposely kept spaces in-front of option and select because I was not aware of any other way to display raw html source in my query here on stackoverflow. It was getting converted to actual select options in the preview hence I put those spaces. The actual html source is exactly what you pasted.
I don't know why the XPath query is not working in JMeter. Did you get the output as 43 in JMeter or you used a XPath evaluator to do that?
I've added the extractor to the sampler which gives me the above response. And i've used the extractor's reference name as a parameter in another request.

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar: I have not used JMeter but am using XMLSPY to test the XPATH. I have updated answer with another XPATH which will give result according to where selected attribute is available

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML (not XML!..) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).

And use better refined xpath query from Siva's answer below.

Comment: Yeah I did not have Use Tidy (tolerant parser) checked. Thank you! And yes I used the refined xpath query from Siva's answer.